# Store form data into wordpress database

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I have created a simple html form to test, how I can insert data in wpdb. I know how to do it in PHP but in wordpress I am getting confused!

```
global $wpdb;
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['r1s1']; //Here r1s1 is name of the form control
    $email = $_POST['r2s1'];
    $contact = $_POST['r3s1'];
    $address = $_POST['r5s1'];
    if ($name != '' || $email != '') {
        $post = $wpdb->insert(
                'table', array(
                    'feild' => $name,
                    'dev' => $email,
                    'tenant' => $contact,
                    'mod' => $address,
                ), array(
                    '%s',
                    '%s',
                    '%s',
                    '%s'
                )
        );
        echo $post;
        if ($post) {
            echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";
        } else {
            echo "<br/><br/><span>Insertion Failed...!!</span>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";
    }
}
```

When I click on submit button then it shows message `insertion failed...!!` ( Message that I am printing via echo). This code is written in template. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: In which table you insert this data

Comment: @Ankur Bhadania Table that I have created in wordpress database.

Comment: Check this link form more information https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: `tenant ` fields value int or string

Comment: all are string values.. And i have already read that codex! its only shows queries, it dont show how to link with form.

Comment: your code is working fine with all string value. please database table structure of $_post value

Comment: In my table structure I have one auto increment field of `int` type and 4 fields of `varchar` type. Thats all! Do I need something more in my  table structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert( 'table_name', array( 'field_name' => $_POST['r1s1'], 'field_name' => $_POST['r2s1'],'field_name' => $_POST['r3s1'],'field_name' => $_POST['r4s1']) );
```

Try This one

Comment: Its worked perfectly fine! BUT Why...  My code was also correct (Ankur Bhadania told me in op that he tested my code and its working). AND purvik7373 also gave me his answer like you. He gave me his tested code with screenshot. Why their code didn't work in my localhost (Same code was working in his localhost). AND why your code works for me! Please explain..

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code?

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "your_table_name";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['r1s1']; //Here r1s1 is name of the form control
    $email = $_POST['r2s1'];
    $contact = $_POST['r3s1'];
    $address = $_POST['r5s1'];
    $data = array(
        'feild' => $name,
        'dev' => $email,
        'tenant' => $contact,
        'mod' => $address
    );

    if ($name != '' || $email != '') {
        $result = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $data);          
        if ($result) {
            echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";
        } else {
            echo "<br/><br/><span>Insertion Failed...!!</span>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please print all variables for make sure variables has values. ex: `print_r($data); die;`

Comment: did you have those field in your db table? 
ex: `feild`, `dev`, `tenant`, `mod`

Comment: Yes variable is printing the values and my table has all these fields. I know name of the fields are meaningless, since this is only for testing so I didn't bother much.

Comment: Hi bro, I just check above code in my localhost and it's working fine please cross check db field type. and also check your db field name space or something else. http://screencast.com/t/XH1ODl7Oce7s

Comment: Yes I gave my table name. May be I shud check it by creating new form! I will tell you after I test a new form with this code

Comment: Ok other form is also not working! May be the problem is something else, Not the code (since its displaying variable's value). Mine code was also correct I guess.